# WP7 Splash Screen showing everytime user goes to home page

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've added a splash screen to my Windows 7 Phone app but it displays every time the user goes back to the home page.  I'm trying to figure out how I can only show the splash screen during the application launch.  I've tried adding a bool "firstLoad" to the App.xaml.cs and setting it to false when Application_Activated is run but that did not work.

My splash screen is handled by the main page.  The method is called ShowPopup

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Popup popup;
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;
    private bool firstLoad = true;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Only want to do this once
        ShowPopup();
    }
}

    private void ShowPopup()
    {
        if (firstLoad)
        {
            this.popup = new Popup();
            this.popup.Child = new PopUpSplash();
            this.popup.IsOpen = true;
            StartLoadingData();
        }
        firstLoad = false;
    }
```

Comment: I assume that ShowPopup checks the value of `firstLoad` to determine whether to display the popup? You should also explicitly initialize `firstLoad` to true.

Comment: I added the ShowPopup method to show that I am checking firstLoad.  The issue seems to be that the value is being reset every time the user goes to the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Added global variable to App.xaml.cs.  Set variable to false in MainPage.xaml.cs when ShowPopup() is run.  Problem solved